# A word for the action of offering bad deals

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

**Situation (imaginary and hyperbolic to establish the point)**

There are two types of candies available in a shop. Type one is sweet and savory, but type two is infested with a serious bacteria, but coloured nicely.

People also buy candy type #2, for whatever reason.

I go to the shop. I am not allowed to enter. Other people are allowed to enter. Eventually, candy type #1 is fully sold out.

At this point I am suddenly welcomed with a lot of gusto. I see that only candy type #2 is available.

The shopkeeper asks "Do you have a candy?".

I say, "Nah, I was not allowed to enter the shop".

They answer, "Never mind, look, we are offering candy type #2. You can have them all. You are the only one we will sale candy #2"

**Question**

Is there a single word that specifically describes the *mal-intent* of trying to sell candy type #2, knowing that it has the bacterial infection?

I would prefer a single word, if not possible then a phrase is okay. If there is a figure of speech or an idiom to this effect, I'd be very interested in knowing that.

If a word describing the intent is not possible (or in any case) is there a word that describes the bad-deal disguised as a great reward?

**Attempt to Solve**

"Mal-intent" as a word is too generic. I am seeking a word that describes mal-intent of pushing a bad deal.

"Platitude" covers the empty words that could be used to push such a deal, but it does not necessarily imply that the deal is seriously bad.

"Bad deal" again is too direct.

**Part of speech**

I expect this to be a noun, but I am not setting a requirement. I am still learning.

**Application**

"*I am tired of your _________________*. "

The answer goes in the blank.

Comment: The example used is confusingly overelaborate. The presence of the first kind of candy is irrelevant to the question, as is not being allowed to enter the shop.

Comment: What is the bigger motive for the bad deal giver in your example? Profiteering? Harming the receiver? Or both?

Comment: @banuyayi: Profiteering by selling the leftover, even if that harms the receiver - potentially by artificially making grandiose advertisements about the leftovers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb **foist** according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/foist) means "to offer (something fake, useless, or inferior) as genuine, useful, or valuable".

They give an example:

> shopkeepers who foist shoddy souvenirs on unsuspecting tourists

You could use the verbal noun **foisting**.

Comment: This sounds like a good choice

Answer (score 3):

I believe the phrasal verb ***palm off*** is the closest it gets.

> to get rid of someone or something that you do not want, by persuading someone else to take or buy them from you - *[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/palm-off)*

A noun won't be as precise in my opinion and you've mentioned that it doesn't have to be a noun. You could possibly use it as a verbal noun like "your palming off" but it is not a common usage; so it is better to rephrase your sentence to use "palm off" as a phrasal verb. The closest noun that came to my mind was *sham* but it might be still too general; as it means a fake, an imitation or trickery.

Comment: Agreed. I could not find it in my own mental recesses.

Answer (score 0):

*Deceit* just means lying in general but could certainly apply to making a deal that you know is bad.

*Fraud* is the crime of making a deal that you know is bad.

I'm not sure how accurate your example is; these words don't feel strong enough for intentionally keeping somebody out so you can sell them poisoned candy. That's an assassination attempt!

Comment: replace candy with a job opportunity, a promotion opportunity, or an opportunity to, pick a topic in a team project, or something  like that. It happens in several places